# How can i allign this text horizzontal?

Tags: html, css

Hi i want to align the h4 to the p text, i've tried with display: inline-block, but it doesn't work someone can help me? thank you to all the answer!

```html
<h4>2.1</h4><p> Vietato bestemmiare/insultare/offendere/discriminare/volgarit&agrave;/razzismo in <strong>CHAT/VOCALE</strong>.</p>
```

Comment: What are you trying? Align in the sense?

Comment: i want to show the h4 to the left of the p, not above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should fix it:

```
h4, p {
  display: inline;
}
```

This happens because the `h4` and `p` tags have default display property set to "block", which places each one on its own line.

Comment: yes this work but i have more than one line like that and if i do this that appear all line inline

Comment: In that case, it's best to apply a class/ID to the `h4` and `p` elements that you want to appear inline.

Comment: i have a page of rules i can't do it, i have 30 line like that

Comment: Are you allowed to use javascript/jQuery?

Comment: Or if not, you can wrap all the lines inside a `div`, and use the selectors `div > h4` and `div > p` to style

Comment: ah wait i can add <br> at the end of every line